# Setting up Rails to work with sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby

Ok I followed the steps for setting up ruby and rails on my Vista machine and I am having a problem connecting to the database.

### Contents of `database.yml`

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  database: APPS_SETUP
  Host: WindowsVT06\SQLEXPRESS
  Username: se
  Password: paswd
```

Run `rake db:migrate` from myapp directory

```
----------
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- deprecated
```

### **ADO**

I have dbi 0.4.0 installed and have created the ADO folder in

`C:\Ruby\lib\ruby\site_ruby\1.8\DBD\ADO`

I got the ado.rb from the dbi 0.2.2

What else should I be looking at to fix the issue connecting to the database? Please don't tell me to use MySql or Sqlite or Postgres.

****UPDATE****

I have installed the activerecord-sqlserver-adapter gem from --source=http://gems.rubyonrails.org

Still not working.

I have verified that I can connect to the database by logging into SQL Management Studio with the credentials.

---

**rake db:migrate --trace**

---

```
PS C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myapp> rake db:migrate --trace
(in C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/myapp)
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- deprecated
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:27:in `gem_original_require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:27:in `require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:355:in `new_constants_in'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/dbi.rb:48
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:27:in `gem_original_require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:27:in `require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:355:in `new_constants_in'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/requires.rb:7:in `require_library_
or_gem'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnin
gs'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/requires.rb:5:in `require_library_
or_gem'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-1.0.0.9250/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver
_adapter.rb:29:in `sqlserver_connection'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specificatio
n.rb:292:in `send'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specificatio
n.rb:292:in `connection='
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specificatio
n.rb:260:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specificatio
n.rb:78:in `connection'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:408:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:373:in `new'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:373:in `up'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:356:in `migrate'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.1.1/lib/tasks/databases.rake:99
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.2/lib/rake.rb:621:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.2/lib/rake.rb:621:in `execute'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.2/lib/rake.rb:616:in `each'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.2/lib/rake.rb:616:in `execute'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.2/lib/rake.rb:582:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.2/lib/rake.rb:575:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.2/lib/rake.rb:568:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.2/lib/rake.rb:2031:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.2/lib/rake.rb:2009:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.2/lib/rake.rb:2009:in `each'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.2/lib/rake.rb:2009:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.2/lib/rake.rb:2048:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.2/lib/rake.rb:2003:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.2/lib/rake.rb:1982:in `run'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.2/lib/rake.rb:2048:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.2/lib/rake.rb:1979:in `run'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.2/bin/rake:31
C:/Ruby/bin/rake:19:in `load'
C:/Ruby/bin/rake:19
PS C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myapp>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same problem yesterday. Apparently 'deprecated' is a gem, so you want to run "gem install deprecated" to grab and install the latest version. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

I used and ODBC data source and the SQL Server adapter on Windows Server 2008 against SQL Server 2000 running on a remote instance.

**Install SQL Server Adapter**

```
gem.bat install activerecord-sqlserver-adapter
  Successfully installed deprecated-2.0.1
  Successfully installed dbi-0.4.1
  Successfully installed dbd-odbc-0.2.4
  Successfully installed activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.2.22
  4 gems installed
```

**Create an ODBC datasource**

- Type: SQL Server
- Name: rails_development
- Description:  rails_development
- Server: SERVER
- SQL Authentication (sa/12345)
- Default Database: DATABASE

**Setup database.yml**

```
development:
    adapter: sqlserver
    mode: odbc
    dsn: rails_development
    username: sa
    password: 12345
```

**YMMV**

A couple of helpful links:

- http://rubyrailsandwindows.blogspot.com/2008/03/rails-2-and-sql-server-2008-on-windows_24.html
- http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowToUseLegacySchemas

Answer (score 2):

Did you install the SQL Server adapter?

```
gem install activerecord-sqlserver-adapter --source=http://gems.rubyonrails.org
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a 64 bit machine, there are two ODBC administrator programs, one for 32 bit and one for 64 bit. activerecord-sqlserver-adapter looks for DSNs set up with the 32 bit version.

Answer (score 1):

Correct link is http://rubyrailsandwindows.blogspot.com/2008/03/rails-2-and-sql-server-2008-on-windows_24.html

Answer (score 0):

I too had faced this problem. There is another work around.
You can create a DSN for the app db from control panel->admin tools->Odbc.
Database.yml file should look like below:

```
adapter: sqlserver
mode: odbc
dsn: DSN_NAME
host: localhost
database: App_development
username: uname
password: password
```

I tried using the deprecated gem, wasn't of much use.
I had tried installing an ADO adaptor too which rendered useless.