# rails & sql server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, database, odbc

I am trying to connect sql server from rails

I've added gems

```
gem 'ruby-odbc'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
```

now I am trying to configure **database.yml** but I am doing it wrong

please paste an example of the configuration file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this question:

[Setting up Rails to work with sqlserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130547/setting-up-rails-to-work-with-sqlserver)

Your database.yml should look something like this:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  database: database_name
  host: server_name
  username: user_name
  password: your_pw_here
```