# Connect Sql server in Ruby on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server

I am newbie to `ruby on rails`. I want to know how to connect `Sql server` to the rails application.

Iam working with RoR in windows environment. Is there any link to set up connection with `SQL Server` in ROR?

Comment: Docs: [Configuring Rails Applications: 3.18 Configuring a Database](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't done it on Windows, but if it's anything like connecting to postgresql on a mac you have to:

1. Have sql-server running locally (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143219.aspx ?)
2. Add a gem to your gemfile that will allow Rails to talk to
   sql-server, probably this:
   https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter |
   `gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~> 3.1.0'`
3. Update your database.yml file for sql server, example here: [Setting up Rails to work with sqlserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130547/setting-up-rails-to-work-with-sqlserver) (plus it's also the answer)
4. Then you would just create the db and migrate it. On a mac it's like
   this `rake db:create && rake db:migrate`