# Connect rails with sql server 2012 remotly

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server

i have Linux fedora installed on machine and also i am working with rails project and i have SQL server 2012 on another machine .... i want to connect rails with SQL server 2012 remotely. How can i do this ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect Sql server in Ruby on rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194977/connect-sql-server-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following gems for connecting sql server :

```
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
```

And the `database.yml` should look like this:

```
development:
  mode: dblib
  adapter: sqlserver
  host: <host or ip> 
  database: <DBNAME>
  username: uname
  password: password
  timeout: 0
```

you can check gems documentation for further usage.

Comment: thanks ranzit , is there any configuration i have to do it with sql server side?

Comment: nothing needed. You need that database name and password and the host ip. Thats it

Comment: thanks ranzit , but i have the sql server on another machine ... what about FreeTds ? have i to use it ?